# CSS Selector Specificity

Tags: css

```
.input-solve[input-solve="a"]{ border: 1px solid #0000ff; color: #0000ff; }
.input-solve[input-solve="b"]{ border: 1px solid #008000; color: #008000; }
.input-solve[input-solve="c"]{ border: 1px solid #b40036; color: #b40036; }
.input-solve[input-solve="a"]:after{ background-color: #0000ff; }
.input-solve[input-solve="b"]:after{ background-color: #008000; }
.input-solve[input-solve="c"]:after{ background-color: #b40036; }
//
.input-solve[input-solve="a1"]{ border: 1px solid #0000ff; color: #0000ff; }
.input-solve[input-solve="b1"]{ border: 1px solid #008000; color: #008000; }
.input-solve[input-solve="c1"]{ border: 1px solid #b40036; color: #b40036; }
.input-solve[input-solve="a1"]:after{ background-color: #0000ff; }
.input-solve[input-solve="b1"]:after{ background-color: #008000; }
.input-solve[input-solve="c1"]:after{ background-color: #b40036; }
```

**How can I make them shorter? like**
.input-solve[input-solve=*"a,a1"*]{ border: 1px solid #0000ff; color: #0000ff; }

Answer (score 4):

Use `^=` in place of `=` (which means an attribute *[starting with](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)*) and use `currentColor` to shorten the code and avoid repetition

```
.input-solve[input-solve^="a"]{ color: #0000ff; }
.input-solve[input-solve^="b"]{ color: #008000; }
.input-solve[input-solve^="c"]{ color: #b40036; }

.input-solve[input-solve] { border: 1px solid; }
.input-solve[input-solve]::after { background-color: currentColor; }
```

Note that you may omit the `border-color`, since by default is inherited from the current color set on the element.

Comment: Thx for explanat. but, my question for make "a" and "a1" be in a line. Can I?
bcs, there's so many input function with same color.

Comment: No, you can't inline values. This approach  is the best you can do with the given selectors.

Answer (score -1):

Using SASS

> ```
> .input-solve
>     &[input-solve="a"]
>         border: 1px solid #0000ff color: #0000ff
>         &::after
>             background-color: #0000ff
>
>     &[input-solve="b"]
>         border: 1px solid #008000 color: #008000
>         &::after
>             background-color: #0000ff
>
>     &[input-solve="c"]
>         border: border: 1px solid #b40036 color: #b40036
>         &::after
>             background-color: #0000ff
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered adding ID's on the elements along side classes and then using the ID selector to make the changes to the specific elements? An example would be;

```
<div class="input-solve" id="solve_a">CONTENT HERE</div>
<div class="input-solve" id="solve_b">CONTENT HERE</div>
```

Then you can select the ID rather than the class, here is an example;

```
#solve_a{
 border: 1px solid #0000ff; color: #0000ff;
}
```

I hope that I am understanding your question. If not you may want to consider offering more information as not everyone reads text the same way.

Comment: They are asking how to make their code shorter, I don't think that using an id attribute instead of a class can significantly reduce it or simplify (you're in fact introducing more specificity in your selectors)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I did make the code shorter. I agree with what you are saying though and like your answer. I was simply offering an alternative solution. I noticed tht you didnt leave a comment for Fedoro who's answer is in fact longer. Do you not like me?